# Converting Hex to XML

Tags: xml, hex

I am trying to take save data from a PlayStation and convert it to a file that works for pc. The files can only be read in XML, but the PlayStation file is in Hex. Is there any way to convert the file from hex code, to XML, without having to rewrite the entire file myself?

I have tried a couple of things with no luck. I have no real background in this.

[The original file from the PlayStation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WufGY.png)

[What the file needs to be formatted in for the game to be able to read it on PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGU3i.jpg)

[Another Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkQOf.png)

Comment: Do you have a reference that you can give us a link to that says the files are XML?

Comment: When you say the file is "in hex", all you are really telling us is that it's a binary file whose bytes can be displayed in hexadecimal. Well, all files are binary and can be displayed in hexadecimal, so this tells us nothing about what's really in the file. Playstation like any other platform supports all sorts of file formats like PNG, MP3, AVI, etc, and you're going to have to know more about what it is before you can do anything with it. Similarly, telling us you want it in XML tells us nothing: that could be Music XML, OpenOffice XML, or 1000 other formats.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I just added screenshots of the files in my original post to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @MichaelKay  I just added screenshots of the files in my original post to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @SmileyNriley It may depend on the game - if it does not have the option to save the game data to the cloud and load it onto a PC, then the data may be encrypted to prevent transferring the game data manually.

Comment: The file is encrypted.  See playstation documentation : https://www.psdevwiki.com/ps4/Save_Data

Comment: Unless you can find documentation telling you how to interpret the binary data, you're hosed.